# How to adapt createRecord().save() to expect empty response?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When persisting a record to the backend via createRecord('record-name').save(), my backend responds with a 200 and an empty body. The empty body causes the flow to break rasing an error.

How can I adapt on that situation w/o changing the backend?

Comment: you must use clinet side generated ìds then. Whats the http status code? `201` or `204`?

Comment: It's 200 actually

Comment: You're using client side generated ids?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that the response's content-type is: text/html. How can I consume that?

Comment: basically just override the adapter. Just ensure `createRecord` does not fail.